# Which is the correct source for the correct German Lohnsteuer deduction?

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, germany, software

Coming from [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102458/tax-deduction-macros-in-python-for-germany), I have now the following data and must say I'm quite puzzled.

Which value is correct now?

- **#1** Given the reference data from a [German software company](https://www.lohnexperte.de/files/root-pdfs/pdf/Muster.pdf) specializing on tax software. In their sample loan paychecks, they give for example for a monthly brutto income of **EUR 4926.59** (all further values in euro, and always *Lohnsteuerklasse I*). This corresponds to the *Lohnsteuer* tax fee **1000.75**.
- **#2** Then if you take the popular site [brutto-netto-rechner.info](https://www.brutto-netto-rechner.info/) it gives you **1003.16**.
- **#3** There are also [official government documents](https://www.bmf-steuerrechner.de/interface/programmablauf.xhtml) for tax deduction available as XML which an [open source project](https://github.com/jenner/LstGen) can transform to program code in some popular languages. My take on it with its Python product outputs **1247.91**.
- **#4** Official [German tax tool](https://www.bmf-steuerrechner.de/fb/fb2018/eingabeformfb2018.xhtml) gives **1027**.
- **#5** Finally, my [own take](https://github.com/german-tax-python/lohnsteuer) on the [Wikipedia formula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lohnsteuer_(Deutschland)) with Python gives **936.91**.

This can't be?! I must really think of the [Blue Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Tigers) story by J.L.Borges.

**UPDATE after the question was answered / solution**

Thanks to this community the following code works for me based on #3; in #2 it works as well but they have rounding errors. Others I have not double-checked.

```
def test_lohnexample1(self):

        # source: https://www.lohnexperte.de/files/root-pdfs/pdf/Muster.pdf

        brutto = 4926.59 * 100 # Brutto in ¢ent

        l = Lohnsteuer2018()
        l.setRe4(brutto) # cent

        l.setStkl(1) # Steuerklasse
        l.setLzz(2) # Lohnzahlungszeitraum, 2 = Monat

        l.setZkf(1) # Kinder

        l.setPkv(0) # GKV (default)
        l.setKvz(1.5) # Krankenkassenzusatzbeitrag (1.50%) 
        l.setKrv(0) # RV-WEST (default)

        l.setAlter1(0) # setze 1, wenn das 64. Lebensjahr zu Beginn des Kalenderjahres vollendet wurde
        l.setAf(0) # # 1, wenn die Anwendung des Faktorverfahrens gewählt wurden (nur in Steuerklasse IV)
        l.setF(1) # Faktor
        l.setPvs(0) # Nur wenn in Sachsen
        l.setR(0) # Religion ja/nein
        l.setLzzhinzu(0) # Hinzurechnungsbetrag auf der Lohnsteuerkarte
        l.setPvz(0) # 1, wenn Zuschlag zur sozialen Pflegeversicherung

        l.MAIN()
        print("results lohnexample1:")
        print_lst(l)

        steuer = math.floor(float(l.getLstlzz()) + float(l.getStv()) + float(l.getSts())) / 100.0
        soli = math.floor(float(l.getSolzlzz()) + float(l.getSolzs()) + float(l.getSolzv())) / 100
        stges = steuer + soli

        assert steuer == 1000.75
        assert soli == 42.20
```

Comment: If there's indeed such variance on the subject, I would consult a licensed in German tax law advisor than listen to anything further on an online forum tbh.

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies like children, _Freibetraege_, etc., but the government publishes _tables_ (not a formula), which are binding. I would trust those most.

Comment: @Aganju I used governmental XML description of calculation workflows, so the formulae are there, see link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aganju has it right that there are many variables. Consider in particular *Kinderfreibetrag* (Kfb) and *Krankenkassenzusatzbeitrag* (1.50%) in your first source. Put exactly the same variables into your second source and the result is the same, to the cent. I expect that the same will be true for the 4th source.

Comment: thank you @WerKater now it works for me! 

Adding the two facts you have pointed out in the source code based on the source #3, I get exactly same values as in #1. With #2 it works as well but I think they have some rounding errors.

For those who is interested in more detailed I added a summary as an update to the question.